# How can I move disk space to drive :C with ssd card from :D with regular hard drive?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, disk-space

I am left with 2GB free space on drive C and over 800 GB free on drive D.

**How can I change that and bring more space to C or combine C and D ?**

**What I have been trying so far:**

1) Combining C and D into once piece, that didn't work and the reason I figured is because my C and D drivers are made from different hardware.

2) Using partition software: My OS (Windows 10) blocked me from doing this action.

3) Reading on forums realizing the only solution I have is buying a bigger SSD card.

**System info:**

My OS: Windows 10.

My D drive: Regular hard disk 1TB.

My C Drive: SSD card 128 GB.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible to merge two or more physical storage devices (SSD or HDD) into a large partition, but if not all those storage device are the same, then all of them will be throttled to the weakest device. In your case, your HDD will only have 128GB usable storage and SSD will run at the speed of HDD. This technique is called RAID, Redundant Array of Inexpensive (some people say Independent) Disks. It will erase all your data when creating the RAID. So yes, it is possible, but no, it does not fit your needs.

Your best solution, beside getting a larger SSD, is to mount your HDD into a folder in your C drive and move rarely used files into HDD. If you already have files in your HDD, you may want to divide it into two partition and mount the new one. After this is set up, none of the file path will be broken, all your shortcuts and softwares will work normally. Your C drive must be using NTFS file system. For detailed steps, [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753321(v=ws.11).aspx) are official guide from Microsoft.